# Automating Internet Explore via PowerShell - Select multiple check boxes not working

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

> ## Logs into site

```
$usernameMI = "myusername"
$passwordMI = "mypassword"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("https://mobility-vsp1.corp.com/mifs/login.jsp")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= $usernameMI
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = $passwordMI
$ie.document.getElementById("login-btn").click();
```

> ## This part below will prompt for first and last name then search for the device and user

```
while($ie.busy -eq $ture) 
{
start-sleep -milliseconds 1000;
}


$Devicesearch = Read-Host 'Enter email alias (Example: First.Last)'
$ie.document.getElementById("simpleSearch-1099-inputEl").value = $Devicesearch
$ie.document.getElementById("ext-gen1231").click();
```

> ## This is where I can not select the checkbox (this checkbox checks all checkboxes when clicked)
>
> ## In order to do this I tried pulling out the embedded object this will give the checkbox a value I can manipulate, but I have not gotten it to work.
>
> ## I have tried id.document.getElementById("gridcolumn-1145-textEl").click without piping but that didn't work either

```
$chkbox = $ie.document.getElementById("gridcolumn-1145-textEl")
($chkbox | where {$_.tagName -eq "x-grid-row-checker-on"}).selected
```

Comment: Is the problem that you're not able to check the checkbox, or that you're not able to select the intended checkbox?

Comment: I am not able to check the check box that checks all the check boxes below it. Therefore if I could select the check box it would select all the check boxes within the search parameters I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you clicked on the wrong element.
Would you please check this "ext-gen1231" to see if it has an onclick value.
I have just gone through this and there are two elements with similar title and I clicked the second one and it worked.